# jQuery - element crossing another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fixed div on the page which contains a logo and as the user scrolls and this logo passes over other divs I wnat to the change the colour of the logo.

I have this working over a single div but need to it work across multiple so any help appreciated.

The WIP site can be seen here... [dd.mintfresh.co.uk](https://dd.mintfresh.co.uk/) - if you scroll down you'll (hopefully) see the logo change from black to white as it crosses an illustrated egg. I need the same to happen when it crosses other divs further down the page.

The script so far...

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){  

  var fixed = jQuery("logo");
  var fixed_position = jQuery("#logo").offset().top;  
  var fixed_height = jQuery("#logo").height();     

  var toCross_position = jQuery("#egg").offset().top;  
  var toCross_height = jQuery("#egg").height();

  if (fixed_position + fixed_height  < toCross_position) { 
    jQuery("#logo img").css({filter : "invert(100%)"}); 
  } else if (fixed_position > toCross_position + toCross_height) {  
    jQuery("#logo img").css({filter : "invert(100%)"});
  } else {    
    jQuery("#logo img").css({filter : "invert(0%)"});  
  }
}
);
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to fire a div scroll event. you can assign

```
           $("div1").scroll(function(){ 
                   //change the color of the div1
                  } 
              }); 

           $("div2").scroll(function(){ 
                //change the color of the div2
              } 
               });
```

or you can assign a class to divs which you want to change the color

```
          $(".div").scroll(function(){ 
                //change the color of the div which you are scrolling now
                   } 
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :-

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var that = $(this);
   $('.section').each(function() {
    var s = $(this);
    if (that.scrollTop() >= s.position().top) {
      if(s.hasClass('active')) {
        $('.logo').addClass('invert');
      } else {
        $('.logo').removeClass('invert');
      }
   }
   });    
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background: #f00;
  height: 400px;
}
.logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.logo.invert {
  filter: invert(100%);
}
div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://dd.mintfresh.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/DD_logo.svg" class="logo" />
<div id="page1" class="section"></div>
<div id="page2" class="section active"></div>
<div id="page3" class="section"></div>
<div id="page4" class="section active"></div>
<div id="page5" class="section"></div>
```

**As your site code** you can do like this :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var that = $(this);
   $('#content > section').each(function() {
    var s = $(this);
    if (that.scrollTop() >= s.position().top) {
      if(s.hasClass('black')) {
        $('#logo img').css({filter: 'invert(0%)'});
      } else {
        $('#logo img').css({filter: 'invert(100%)'});
      }
      }
   });    
});
```

Comment: Jagieet thanks so much!!  I've implemented your code and it's almost there but for some reason my colour change is firing when the 'active' div comes into view and not when it hits the top of the viewport? Any idaes?

Comment: Are you want to change the color of logo on each div comes into view

Comment: No, I want to chage the colour of the logo when a section with the 'black' class hits the top of the viewport.

Comment: @MintfreshLindfield change `active` class with `black` class

Comment: Thanks Jagieet, but I've done that, if you look at the dev link you'll see what I mean, the logo is changing colour when the div comes into view and not as it hits the top of the viewport?